# CodeIgniter 3.0.0 Project doesn't work on sub domain

Tags: .htaccess

I created a project using CI(version 3.0.0), and it works perfectly in XAMPP localhost. And i upload that project to sub domain then its giving an error [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1kVrl1aySvLdS1NTjNQVmJJUjQ/view?usp=sharing).

I Handle Router's and config setting as well. So what is this error?? how to avoid this?? There are some answers, But not suit for this.

Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'shop';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: its php errors right. check  which version php your sever is using

Comment: Looking at the 3.0.0 source on github, Line 104 has nothing to do with this error. Can you please double check your version?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon in my server PHP version  5.4.38. So this should be work i think

Comment: I meant the code igniter version.. it should be in system/core/codeigniter.php around line 58 will be like `define('CI_VERSION', '3.0.0');`

Comment: @MichaelCoxon define('CI_VERSION', '3.0.0'); this is in line 58 already

Comment: All good, it is just that line 104 in Input.php is not a function or a string in that version. It is a protected array. So the error output doesn't make sense.

Comment: protected $headers = array(); This is in line 104 in input.php

Comment: What happened when you set the timezone correctly using the suggestion in the Runtime Notice that is generated by your Server?

Comment: i did all bro, but no use at all

Comment: CI tries best to **guess** the base url if you keep it empty **but** It's good practice to set `baseurl`. This may or may not solve your issue but you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your controller, model, and other your class to Capitalize.

Example :
your own controller `test.php` change to `Test.php`

It should be work.

Its because your server is Linux, and Linux is case sensitive.