# upload project in web host and 404 page not found

Tags: codeigniter

i have problem with codeigniter 3 , the project work fine in localhost , but when i upload my project in host , i see

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

i remove .httaccess file , remove all of my routes , but dont work.

i have two controller :

```
class test extends CI_Controller {}
class testen extends CI_Controller {}
```

my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

edit:
my routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'isogamsharghedonya';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route["en"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen";
$route["fa"] = "isogamsharghedonya";

$route["en"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/index";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-service"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/service";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-news"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/news";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-tvc"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/video";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-certificate"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/certificate";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-honor"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/honor";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-ceo"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/aboutCeo";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-about-company"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/aboutCompany";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-team"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/aboutTeam";
$route["en/isogam-sharghe-donya-contact"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/contact";
$route["en/send-message"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/sendMail";
$route["en/insulation-orders"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/order";
$route["en/new-insulation-orders"] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/newOrder";


$route["fa"] = "isogamsharghedonya/index";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("خدمات-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/service";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("اخبار-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/news";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("تیزر-های-تبلیغاتی-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/video";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("گواهینامه-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/certificate";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("افتخارات-و-جوایز-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/honor";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("مدیر-عامل-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/aboutCeo";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("درباره-شرکت-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/aboutCompany";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("تیم-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/aboutTeam";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("تماس-با-ایزوگام-شرق-دنیا")] = "isogamsharghedonya/contact";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("ارسال-پیام")] = "isogamsharghedonya/sendMail";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("سفارش-ایزوگام")] = "isogamsharghedonya/order";
$route["fa/" . rawurlencode("سفارش-جدید-ایزوگام")] = "isogamsharghedonya/newOrder";

require_once (BASEPATH . 'database/DB' . EXT);
require_once (BASEPATH . 'helpers/url_helper' . EXT);
require_once (BASEPATH . 'helpers/text_helper' . EXT);
$db = &DB();

$query = $db -> get('news');
$result = $query -> result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row -> subjectFA)));
    $route["fa/news/" . $string] = "isogamsharghedonya/newsDetails/$row->id";
}

$query = $db -> get('news');
$result = $query -> result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row -> subjectEN)));
    $route["en/news/" . $string] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/newsDetails/$row->id";
}

$query = $db -> get('product');
$result = $query -> result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row -> nameFA)));
    $route["fa/product/" . $string] = "isogamsharghedonya/productDetails/$row->id";
}

$query = $db -> get('product');
$result = $query -> result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row -> nameEN)));
    $route["en/product/" . $string] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/productDetails/$row->id";
}

$query = $db -> get('trailer');
$result = $query -> result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row -> nameFA)));
    $route["fa/video/" . $string] = "isogamsharghedonya/videoDetails/$row->id";
}

$query = $db -> get('trailer');
$result = $query -> result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row -> nameEN)));
    $route["en/video/" . $string] = "isogamsharghedonyaen/videoDetails/$row->id";
}
```

Comment: in your route file i didn't find any route for `test` and `testen` class have tried by adding route for these controller?

Comment: test=isogamsharghedonya and testen=isogamsharghedonyaen

Comment: have you uploaded your `.htaccess` file in your live server?

Comment: yes, but dont work!, i upload 10 - 11 project in live server , but this one , make me in trouble

Comment: can you replace your .htaccess file with this-
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule> `

Comment: i replace it , but still have have problem

Comment: What is set to $config['base_url'] in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` file?
Side note: it is unnecessary to have those queries in `routes.php`. Perfectly enough, according to documentations would be: `$route["fa/news/(:any)"] = "isogamsharghedonya/newsDetails/$1";` and so on.

Comment: $config['base_url'] ='' , i do this method of route in another project , and work fine.

Comment: Maybe is something server related. Try to set it to project root directory and check result. Pay attention at side not I pointed on.

Comment: Do you get home page/just domain?

Comment: i got domain / host .

Comment: Host - meaning? Expected page or what?

Comment: i cant undertand what you say:"get home page/just domain"

Comment: my problem is i dont see any error  or page that show me where am i wrong , just 404 error page.

Comment: So problem on live server starts in `isogamsharghedonya` as default controller?

Comment: Without code of that controller we can only check the crystal bowl what could be. :)

Comment: are you using CI 3.0.0??

Comment: @QuestionMark Check this kindly. I got same problem. Finely get settle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769516/codeigniter-3-0-0-project-doesnt-work-on-sub-domain

Comment: i confused, because my project work fine in local host!, if any problem , it must show in localhost too...

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and model files must begin with a capital letter.
An example: controllers/Index.php, models/Index_model.php

code in CI 3 core for controllers load (/system/core/router.php):

protected function _set_default_controller()
    {

```
    //... blah-blah-blah ...

    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php'))
    {
        // This will trigger 404 later
        return;
    }

    //...blah-blah-blah...

}
```

It work in localhost, because you system is Windows. Unix like systems is case sensitive in work with files.

Answer (score -1):

As i reviewed your code the first thing that you have rectify is that the way you have declare your controller since it is a good practice to define your controller as `class Test extends CI_Controller` instead of `class test extends CI_Controller` as you have declared some time it might create error and the second thing is that you have to check your `.htaccess` file is uploaded to your root directory of the project and as well as you also check in your routes file whether you have written the appropriate routing rule for your declared controller as well as the is the method is present in your class which is defined in your routes for the same