# Codeigniter throws 404 after uploading to server

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My project runs well on localhost but throws a 404 when I upload the files to a server. Wnen I try to access another page on the system, eg www.myadress.com/newController it throws a 500 internal server error. What could be the problem? This is what my routes look like

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: place `.htaccess` file as i mentioned

Comment: What version of codeigniter you using?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769516/codeigniter-3-0-0-project-doesnt-work-on-sub-domain/29770665#29770665

Comment: am using version 3.0.0

Comment: Check that your controller has a capital letter like Welcome.php instead of welcome.php and also it could be do to your .htaccess you can get some htaccess from here https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter if your controller is home make sure in application/controllers/Home.php

Comment: And home controller would be your main url like `www.myadress.com` because it your default controller http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: thank you @wolfgang1983 the problem was with the capitalization of the controllers and models. it's now working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this.

in **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

in **.htaccess** (This should place **out side application folder**)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

in **autoload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: I have changed the files as advised but its still not working

Comment: can you provide me site URL??

Comment: problem with your controller name

Comment: `http://newmafya.cardplanetsolutions.co.ke/index.php/welcome` is working. did you upload .htacess file?? confirm that once again

Comment: yes I've confirmed that I uploaded the .htaccess. But even when I try another controller it still throws a 404

Comment: what is your controller name??

Comment: the default controller is home. There is also a controller named "settled", "voucher" etc

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769516/codeigniter-3-0-0-project-doesnt-work-on-sub-domain/29770665#29770665

Comment: @muoki_D happy to help