# 404 error codeigniter when upload on server

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, codeigniter

When i hit url https://www.domainname.com/welcome. It gives me 404 error and

when i hit https://www.domainname.com/Welcome its working fine. My controller name and file name is in capital letter and below is my htaccess.

**Please let me know where i'm going wrong.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On my side both links give 404 status. Are those the real links?

Answer (score 0):

I have get solution from this link. Where you can found similar like problem with solution.

Hope, this will help to fix your 404 error.

[Codeigniter throws 404 after uploading to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840815/codeigniter-throws-404-after-uploading-to-server)

Comment: solution, because my links are working with capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Will you try with this once.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.
in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your base url';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

in .htaccess (This should place out side application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

in autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

using "vhosts.conf" folder. URL's can be made case in sensitive. location : /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf/vhosts.conf

RewriteEngine on
rewritemap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You have to made routes for this on your **routes page** in **config** folder. For Ex-

```
 $route["welcome-page"] = 'Welcome';
```

And call your page like - https://www.domainname.com/welcome-page

Hope this code help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi had the same problem when it works in local and i uploaded to amazon Ec2 server.
I get the solution as : make all controller and mode